# dotnet publish succeeds on dev machine, build agent fails, asp.net Netcoreapp2.1/win-x64

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

On "Hosted VS2017" and self-hosted build agent (Windows Server 2012 R2), running `dotnet publish` with a publish profile specified fails with:

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.502\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,5):
>   error NETSDK1047: Assets file
>   'C:\agent_work\11\s\\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a
>   target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1/win-x64'. Ensure that restore has
>   run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.1' in the TargetFrameworks
>   for your project. You may also need to include 'win-x64' in your
>   project's RuntimeIdentifiers.

On local dev server (Win10, VS2017, many different .net sdk versions) when I dotnet publish with the exact same command line, everything works great.

I have tried everything from updating VS2017, installing the exact version of .net core SDK and runtime that we're targeting, updating the build agent, windows updates... Nothing seems to help.  I can't understand why it's having different behavior.

The publish profile is a FileSystem profile and has the following two elements specified:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

The command line looks this:  `"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish "C:\agent\_work\11\s\Source\TheProject.csproj" --no-build -c Release -f netcoreapp2.1 /p:PublishProfile="Publish Release To Filesystem.pubxml" -o C:\agent\_work\11\a\Website -v d`

Does anyone have a clue what I can do to get this working?

Comment: Did you run package restore? What does your pipeline look like?

Comment: I've stripped the pipeline down to simply getting code and running dotnet cli tasks.  I have tried a dotnet build, a dotnet restore with a dotnet build --no-restore, and a dotnet publish --no-build, etc.  The stuff it's complaining about doesn't make sense, especially considering it works fine on my dev machine.  What other info can I provide that might make this easier to diagnose?

Comment: and when you pass `-r win-s64` to `dotnet publish`? how did you invoke the publish using a publish profile?

Answer (score 8):

This turns out to be all about the Runtime Identifier.  The confusion arose because I assumed building and publishing from dotnet-cli was as simple as building and publishing from Visual Studio.  Visual Studio's publish was doing a full restore/build with its publish, and the publish profile had the `<RuntimeIdentifier>` set.

I was doing several things wrong.  I wasn't including `-r win-x64` to the restore and build tasks, and I was using `dotnet publish --no-build`.  So that's where one mismatch came from.  The next was that I was running `dotnet test` after build and before publish.  That was wiping out some things that publish needed, not sure what though.

I changed `dotnet test` to include `-p:RuntimeIdentifier=winx64` since apparently it uses -r for reporting output (apparently they're adding -runtime in 2.2).

Some things I learned in the process, dotnet-cli does *NOT* work well with .sln files, at least in build agent's.  It seems to have a big problem with file locks and shared processes.  Trying to optimize build tasks to minimize work with the dotnet-cli is a major pain in the ass.

Answer (score 4):

I think Jay covered this in the other answer, but to clarify what worked for me was running:-

```
dotnet restore <path/to/.sln> -r linux-x64
```

just before running the `dotnet msbuild` command.  (Obviously replace `linux-x64` with your target).